# HTML5 <article> for ecommerce products

Tags: html, dom, tags, seo

The new HTML5 article tag all seems very great and wonderful and there has been much discussion here and elsewhere about its uses.

Unfortunately, all this discussion seems to be in the context of blog or news sites where the content is all just that, content.

In an ecommerce site, the biggest question to be asking is, how do I now mark up a product?

Taking the spec for guidance, it seems that a saleable item is indeed something distinct that could be syndicated (and often is). The article tag seems like a good match, yet I see no mention of its use in this way.

Is it appropriate here but all the examples blogs etc. because they seem to fit a bit more intuitively with the name of the tag? Or am I stretching too hard at the spec?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: As most of the time, you'll want people able to _buy_ a product, I'd hardly say it was 'independent'. Of course, you could provide forms/links in the tag that do just that, but the definition IMHO clashes somewhat with your intended use.

Comment: A news article is independent in the context of a blog site; I'd say the same goes for a product in the context of an ecommerce site. I interpret independent here to mean one of a set.

Comment: Well there we have two nicely contradicting answers. Is the difficulty here in what is meant by "independently distributable or reusable". If that means that it can be wholly consumed separately from the site then I agree, a product does not fit this definition. However, their example of a user submitted comment confuses me - these certainly don't make sense out of context.

Answer (score 17):

See the following quote from the W3C spec. Perhaps `article` is suitable, as a product can be considered an "independent item of content."

> The `article` element represents a component of a page that consists of
> a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site
> and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable,
> e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or
> newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an
> interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of
> content.

Although not using semantic elements, you may wish to look at the [Product schema](http://schema.org/Product) from schema.org.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [this article](http://peteschuster.com/2012/05/semantic-html5-for-products-in-ecommerce/#comment-878)

Looks like `<article>` is not that bad an idea. I am using pointers from [here](http://peteschuster.com/2012/05/semantic-html5-for-products-in-ecommerce/#comment-878) and http://schema.org/Product for an e-commerce site project.